# Touch sensor trouble

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, programming, library, pins

I need help I use Touch Sensor(T)v.0 and it always receives a signal not matter I touched it or not.
Here is the code.

```
#define TOUCH_PIN 7
int touchVal = 0;
  
void setup() {
   Serial.begin(115200);
   pinMode(TOUCH_PIN, INPUT);
}
  
void loop() {
   touchVal = digitalRead(TOUCH_PIN);
   Serial.println(touchVal);
   delay(200);
}
```

Comment: What touch sensor do you have? Please provide a link to the datasheet or to the product page at your reseller. How did you connect it? Is it active HIGH or active LOW? (meaning if touching it makes the output HIGH or LOW, both is possible)

Comment: https://aliexpress.ru/item/32800470168.html?&sku_id=64142657896

Comment: Honestly, I don't  know it's active HIGH or active LOW but it doesn't chengs value when I touched it always print 1

Comment: how do you know that the output is digital ?

Comment: why does your code not look for a change in the output?

Comment: I just want understand does my sensor work or not that's why I haven't output. In this line, I just print the value. Serial.println(touchVal);